# Please explain this nested query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  name  
FROM EMPLOYEE o 
WHERE 
   (SELECT count(*) 
    FROM EMPLOYEE i 
    WHERE i.name < o.name) < 5
```

This gives the top 5 records from the table. Please explain how.

Comment: Why?  There are better ways to implement this logic.

Comment: You are using Less than operator for comparing name field?? Can you explain what exactly you want as the output?

Comment: To me it is a good query to get database concepts improved.

Comment: If you judge this query as equivalent of "give me the topmost 5 `rows`" then it fails. 

The query will return as many rows as is needed to list the first 5 `names` judged by alphabetic sequence. This might be deliberate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you understand table aliasing, your query becomes self-explanatory:

```
SELECT name
FROM EMPLOYEE o     -- <<== Alias #1
WHERE (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM EMPLOYEE i -- <<== Alias #2
    WHERE i.name < o.name) < 5
```

Your query defines two aliases for the same `EMPLOYEE` table.

The query inside counts how many employee names `i` (inner) are "ahead" of employee `o` (outer). If the count of employee names ahead of the current is less than five, the name is returned as a query result.

Note that if there are duplicates among the top names in your table, the number of rows returned by the query may be higher than five.

Comment: Well, count(*) will give out a number say, 10 so it becomes 'where 10<5'. So how's this query actually working?

Comment: @RahulDwivedi `COUNT(*)` will give different number for each row of `EMPLOYEE`. For the rows with names at the top of the list it will give numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, so count < 5 would be true. For the remaining rows the count would be above 5, so count < 5 would be false, and the row would not be selected.

Comment: Let's elaborate this with an example.
Let's say these are the names in the EMPLOYEE table:
name

Das
Blink
Enlight
Rahul
Dwivedi
ABC
XYZ

Now tell me how does the comparison happen in 'i.name<o.name'

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Row `o` will take on each of the seven names during the course of the query. Row `i` will take on each of the seven names each time row `o` is changed (think of two nested loops going through the same array). For row `o` with name `ABC` the count of rows `i` where `i.name < o.name` will be zero, because `ABC` is the first one alphabetically. For Blink it will be 1, because `ABC` is ahead of it. For Das it would be 2, for XYZ it would be 6.

Comment: was just playing around with this query, then I found something strange. If you provide your email address, I'll mail you.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi This site does not work like that: no e-mails or other on-the-side info exchanges are supposed to take place here. If you would like to get some help with this or related query, please post a new question.

Comment: Oh ok. It's alright :) You seem to be the moderator him(her)self..kidding :P

Answer (score 1):

This query makes little sense and doesn't select "top 5 records"; it will select all the rows that qualify according to the correlated subquery.

The subquery is correlated with the outer table reference.  For each row in the table, the subquery counts the number of employees with a name less that the outer reference.  The predicate "less than 5" is applied to the resultant count for each row on the outer table.  The outer row is returned only if there are less than 5 employees with a name less than the current name.

If you have a table with 4 rows with name "Jane" and 100 rows with name with "John", you will get all 100 "John" rows returned because the subquery will return 0 for each "Jane" row and 4 for each "John" row.